# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "req.params.id" at path "_id" for model "Project"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am trying to create a clone of employee management system. I want to implement a feature that when admin opens a details page for any project he will get list of available employees as checkboxes and when select them and submit then those employees will be added to the given project.
I am developing it using Node.js and MongoDB

My project schema is -

```
const ProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  deadline: Date,
  description: String,
  manager:{
    id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
  },
  employees: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        }
    ],
  created_on: { 
    type: Date, 
    default: Date.now
  }

});
```

Form -

```
<form action="/admin/project/<%= project._id %>/addmembers" method="POST">
  <div class="row">
    <% employees.forEach((employee) => { %>
      <% if(!employee.projects.includes(project._id)){ %>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3">
        <input type="checkbox" value="<%= employee._id %>" name="newMembers"> <%= employee.name %> </input>
      </div>
      <% } %>
    <% }); %>
  </div>
<hr class="my-2">
<p class="lead">
  <button class="btn btn-blue btn-lg">Add Members</button>
</p>
</form>
```

Code for handling the request -

```
router.post("/project/:id/addmembers", (req, res) => {
  console.log("add member post route");
  Project.findById(req.params.id, (err, foundProject) => {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      req.flash("error", err.message);
      res.redirect("back");
    } else {
      req.body.newMembers.forEach((employee) => {
        foundProject.employees.push(employee);
      })
      
      foundProject.save()
      console.log(foundProject);
      req.flash("success", "Successfully added new members");
      res.redirect("/admin/project/req.params.id");
    }
  })
});
```

Now whenever I submit form users are added but I always get an error `Cast to ObjectId failed for value "req.params.id" at path "_id" for model "Project"` instead of `success message` now I am new to mongo so I googled it but can't solve my problem can anyone explain me why this error is coming and how can I fix it?

Also I know that if if only one checkbox is selected then req.body.newMembers will not be array. If you can you provide better method to do it, it will be very helpful?

**Update -**
I also tried `findOne()`, `find()`, `findByIdAndUpdate()`, and `id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)` but still get the same error message

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what is happening is you aren't properly handling ids and _id. Given that you haven't mentioned anything, I assume you see this error only once. However, given that the error has to do with the project model/schema, and you use **almost** the same code for both *manager* and *employees*, the error should have to do with a difference between the two. The main difference I see is manager has `id: {*id stuff*}`, but employee has `{*id stuff*}` with no `id:`. However, I don't think this is the actual error, but just something to keep in mind. Try also changing the `id` type to something like `number` just to see if this is related to the issue.

What I think that **actual error** is is the fact that you use `req.params.id` in a `findById()`. This searches your database using the _id. First, having id and _id both is a bit redundant (if you have a reason, that's fine, but _id is something MongoDB needs, so it might be better to just stick with it as it is precreated and handled). Second, you are using a string/int as an id search. To test whether this is the issue, try changing `findById()` to something like `findOne()` or `find()`. Just to clarify, `findById()` doesn't explicitly need an ObjectId, so the type may not be the issue, but `findById()` does handle the search differently than `find({_id: id})`.

Another thing to check is that `req.params.id` actually gives the right value. It should, but this is something to verify. To do so, just `console.log()` it. If this is the problem, try moving `:id` to the end of the path.

**In response to your edit:**
Make sure that the problem doesn't have to do with not having `id:` in the employee (as stated above) and that it doesn't have to do with the `id` being a ObjectId rather than a number. If you change the `id` to a number, make sure to change the search so that it finds the object by `id` not `_id`. Just to let you know, every MongoDB object has an _id (even subobjects like employee and manager), so using `id` is somewhat redundant.

To give you more things to try: make sure you `console.log()` req.params.id to make sure it has the right value. Then, also try commenting sections of code until you find which line it is on. Try hardcoding some input until it works.